# C++ Polymorphic template class, instantiation of template type object

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism, instantiation

I have the following situation, where I want to instantiate an object of a template type.
I want the instantiation of the template type object to depend on the "instantiator" class.

```
template <class T>
class Base
{
public:
  Base(){}

  void do_something()
  {
    T obj = this->Test();
    // do something with object
  }

  virtual T Test()
  {
   return T(5);
  }
};


template <class T>
class Derived : public Base<T>
{
public:
  Derived() : Base<T>() {}
  virtual T Test()
  {
    return T(5, 6);
  }
};

class Test1
{
public:
  Test1(int x){}
};
class Test2 : public Test1
{
public:
  Test2(int x, int y) : Test1(x) {}
};
```

Later in my code I want to work with Base or Derived objects. 
They perform operations on a template type object (`obj`) in function `do_something()`.
I want to let the instantiation of `obj` depend on the implementation
of the `Test()` function.
`Base` should only work with objects of type  `Test1` or derived classes of `Test1` that have the same constructor.
`Derived` should only work on objects that have the same constructor as `Test2`.

```
Base<Test1>(); // works
Base<Test2>(); // doesn't work, but should not work by my design and throw a compile error
Derived<Test1>(); // same
Derived<Test2>();  // should work, but doesn't,
// since Base::Test() still exists, but cannot be compiled due to wrong constructor of T
```

Is there a way to implement the described behavior?
Or is there a design change I can make?

Comment: frankly, your code is full of typos. It is not clear what that code is supposed to achieve. Please explain it or give an example with output and tell us the desired output

Comment: Pleae provide a [mcve]. You fixed some typos but there are still too many.

Comment: You are right, there were a lot of typos I made while quickly writing the question.
I have fixed them and wrote a small explanation of my desired behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You might change Base to be correct for any `T`:

```
template <class T>
class Base
{
public:
    Base(){}

    void do_something()
    {
        T obj = this->Test();
        // do something with object
    }

    virtual T Test()
    {
        if constexpr (std::is_constructible_v<T, int>) {
            return T(5);
        }
        throw std::runtime_error("should not be called");
    }
};
```

but

`Base<Test2>();` would compile but throw at runtime.

Seems better to split and have two derived:

```
template <class T>
class Base
{
public:
    Base() = default;
    virtual ~Base() = default;

    void do_something()
    {
        T obj = this->Test();
        // do something with object
    }

    virtual T Test() = 0;
};

template <class T>
class Derived : public Base<T>
{
public:
  Derived() : Base<T>() {}
  T Test() override { return T(4); }
};

template <class T>
class Derived2 : public Base<T>
{
public:
  Derived() : Base<T>() {}
  T Test() override { return T(5, 6); }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That seems like a good solution. And the abstract base is also a good idea. I initially wanted `Derived` to be completely interchangeable with the same template types, but that would never work. I mean, my example is even designed not to allow that. So I might use your solution.